# How can one reference a link to shared folder with Latex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to add a hyperlink to a shared folder for a PDF I am creating for a workshop. The problem is that I don't know how to close the bracket on my \href instance. Here is some mock code:

```
First, go to \huge \href{\\dadah21s6\woc$  }{ File }
```

The issue is that the closing bracket on the \href{ } <=== will not close because of the "$" symbol.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: The dollar sign is in the folder name?

Comment: @Gowachin yes because it is a shared folder.

Comment: Well then I think you can try this `\$` to insert a $ sign. 
(see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004266/completely-disable-equations-for-rmarkdown-in-rstudio)

Comment: @Gowachin Thank you for finding this for me. I couldn't find it for some odd reason. Needs more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latex interpret the `$` sign to define the beginning and the end of equations. Therefore you must precise you want Latex to **not** interpret these signs with a backslash.

`\$` will return a `$` in the pdf.

For more documentations, see this [pdf in page 19.](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)
Other explanations are located on the [Latex StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex), but not specifically for dollar signs.