# Completely disable equations for rmarkdown in RStudio

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to create an rmarkdown document where I have to work with economic data in US dollars. I have issues with rmarkdown trying to interpret my text as being equations because of the presence of the "$" sign. Specifically, I have two main issues:

1. I cannot disable the automatic preview of equations with RStudio. This is annoying because when there is an automatic preview, I can no longer send selected code to the console with `ctrl + enter`; I have to copy and paste. I have tried to disable outputs inline in RStudio > Global options > R Markdown, but no parameter seem to affect the automatic popup shown in the picture below.

[image: Automatic equation preview in RStudio]

2. When I knit to HTML, my text is interpreted as an equation. I do not want it to be interpreted as an equation (see picture below). Surprisingly, I have not been able to find help for this: there is plethora of help with respect to formatting equations, but almost nothing on how to disable them.

[image: HMTL output with text inappropriately interpreted as equation]

I provide here a minimal reproducible example for this issue:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

The amount of money is US$ billion `r 10` (2017 US$). On average, another thing costed US$ billion `r 50`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\$` to insert a dollar symbol in your text.

Comment: This is great thank you very much. Perfect solution.